# Combobox Database value

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, devexpress

I am making an ASPx and C# form with DevExpress comboboxes and an SQL database.  I've pulled the data to one of the boxes that I need.

I need to assign a variable to one of the fields from the database that are pulled into the combobox.

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox ID="testNameBox" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" 
Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="10px" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
DataSourceID="testSource" ValueType="System.String"
IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains">
    <Columns>
        <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="pkTestKey" Visible="False" />
        <dx:ListBoxColumn FieldName="fkTestCode" Visible="False"  />
        <dx:ListBoxColumn Caption="Test Item Name" FieldName="Name" />
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

The point is that when I choose something in this combobox, another combobox displays related data from another table based on the fkCode value.

How would I pull that variable from this, and use it so that my query for the textbox displays the appropriate data based on that fkCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this demo](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/CascadingComboBoxes.aspx) on DevExpress. You might want to search more about *Cascading Comboboxes*

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>alert("demo for XSS")</script>
```